# Cannot bind a local domain name to my system

Tags: fedora, dns, bind

I have added a new zone to /etc/named.conf as follows:

```
zone "mysite.local" IN {
  type master;
  file "mysite.local.zone";
  allow-update { none; };
};
```

Also, the zone file is as follows:

```
;File name: mysite.local.zone

$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.mysite.local. admin.mysite.local. (
                  3       ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
; name servers - NS records
     IN      NS      ns1.mysite.local.
;     IN      NS      ns2.nyc3.example.com.

; name servers - A records
ns1.mysite.local.          IN      A      192.168.6.30
;ns2.nyc3.example.com.          IN      A       10.128.20.12

; 10.128.0.0/16 - A records
;host1.mysite_local.com.        IN      A      10.128.100.101
;host2.nyc3.example.com.        IN      A      10.128.200.102
```

The named service starts without a problem, but the system cannot resolve mysite.local when I check with nslookup and ping\

Also, I cannot access via browser the domain name that I have created as a VirtualHost in httpd.conf as follows:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  ServerName mysite.local
  ServerAlias www.mysite.local
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
  SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
 <Directory "/var/www/html/public_html">
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  Order allow,deny
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally, this is my ifcfg-eno1 file:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
NAME=eno1
DEVICE=eno1
UUID=9a375715-f0d7-3fa8-8494-6a5d10946f16
ONBOOT=yes
DEVICE=eno1
IPADDR=192.168.6.30
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.6.1
PREFIX=24
DNS1=192.168.6.30
DNS2=8.8.8.8
DEFROUTE=yes
```

I have spent a lot of time on this with no success. I have done this before on a VPS server with static IP and it worked, but on my local network it does not. Could someone tell me where I am messing things up?

Comment: Valentin, resolv.conf includes both dns server IPs. I added NM_CONTROLLED=no but still cannot resolve mysite.local.

Comment: Jason, please tell the audience from what host you are trying to ping. and where. provide some more details. What do the logs on the dns server tell you?

Comment: It is not recommended to use .local as your network's domain name, because it is used by mDNS.

Comment: @ValentinB I am pinging from the dns server itself. It does not know itself.

Comment: Is `192.168.6.30` a recursive or authoritative nameserver? It seems to be both and this is bad, you need to split both roles. Also using as recursive first an internal one and second an external one will both fail to provide you with the service you think it should provide (second nameserver will never be queried until the first one stops to reply at all) and also open you to vulnerabilities as this may leak internal queries outside against your will. Also `ping` is not a DNS troubleshooting tool, and when you use `dig` always specify the nameserver you query to have meaningful replies

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I just want it to be name server in my LAN. So, how can I make it authoritative?